# Mediawiki upgrade on Strato webspace to allow use of PHP version newer than 5.3

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am currently trying to upgrade different older mediawiki versions (1.19, 1.21) to a more recent versions since Strato does no longer support PHP version 5.3.

Those mediawiki installations have originally been installed using the Strato App Wizard, which currently would install mediawiki 1.23.14.

I am aware of the following information:

a.) Strato description on updates of apps
(only in German, but there is no description on updates of mediawiki)

https://www.strato.de/faq/article/2193/So-nehmen-Sie-ein-manuelles-Update-Ihrer-AppWizard-Anwendung-vor.html

b.) Mediawiki Update guide

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading

c.) Compatibility table between different mediawiki and PHP versions
(since my most current need is just to migrate to a newer PHP version which is still supported by Starto)

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Compatibility/de#PHP

Does anyboy have experience with mediawiki upgrades at Strato? Is there any easier way to do an upgrade, e.g. using the app wizard?

Comment: Upgrading MediaWiki is simple: make a backup, replace files, run composer, run update.php. The complications come from some extensions not being compatible with the new core version, but a wizard would not help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer of hirnfred has given some useful hints, but did not work for me, attached is a short bullet point list of the steps which allowed me to upgrade Mediawiki at Strato. The main idea for that solution was to install a new wiki using the built-in AppWizard and then move the contents into the wiki.

- Install new wiki using the app wizard
- Copy modifications (e.g. access restrictions, icon path etc) from old LocalSettings.php file to new LocalSettings.php file
- If applicable, copy old images to new wiki:

  ```
  cd wiki_old
  tar czvf images.tgz images/
  mv wiki_old/images.tgz wiki_new
  cd ../wiki_new
  tar xzvf images.tgz
  ```
- Use automatically generated sql backups of old database, so let's check which are available (using a ssh connection):

  ```
  mysqlbackups Uxxxxxx_old
  ```
- Dump old backup

  ```
  mysqldump --add-drop-table -h mysql_30.08.2017-21:00 -u Uxxxxxx_old -p DBxxxxxx_old> mysql_30.08.2017-21:00.sql
  ```

  (Password for prompt can be found in old LocalSettings.php file)
- Delete tables from new sql database. Access Database via Strato Web Interface using phpmyadmin, select "Struktur"-"selecte all" - "delete"
- Copy SQL data to new database. The new password can be found in the new LocalSettings.php file:

  ```
  mysql -h rdbms -u Uxxxx_new -pxxxxxxx_new DBxxxx_new < mysql_30.08.2017-21:00.sql
  ```
- Execute php update via ssh, in wiki_new/maintenance:

  ```
  php update.php
  ```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the `mediawiki` directory, edit your `.htaccess`. This is responsible for the `php-version` in your wiki.
You can change the contents of the file to this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php71 .php .php4 .php3 .php5 .php71
```

Next, to upgrade your Mediawiki version, download and copy newest `mediawiki-xyz.tar.gz` to the `temp` directory on Strato (I used filezilla for that)

Assuming the new Mediawiki version is `1.29` and your `mediawiki` directory at strato is `mediawiki-01`:

Establish ssh-connection to Strato (I used Putty) and execute at the command-line

```
tar xzf temp/mediawiki-1.29.1.tar.gz -C mediawiki-01/ --strip-components=1
```

Then update your new Installation:

```
cd mediawiki-01/maintenance
php update.php
```

I was successful today with the described method, but no promises or warranties. And making backups before upgrading is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Would be a nice abbreviation for the "official" upgrade guide at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading , but did not work for me, had to fall back on the backup. `php update.php` delivered an unspecified error. Was trying to upgrade from 1.19.1-2 .

Comment: I have tried to do the same with an intermediate version, trying to upgrade to Mediawiki 1.23.14 und using PHP 5.6. While the upgrade process went through, the final layout is currupted. Unfortunately also the backup does not work any longer (meaning it also shows the corrupted style, withe the mediawiki layout missing. All the links and data still there, assume that this is a style issue). Above my paygrade so far.